# proto3-lexer3.c : No such file or directory

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, proto3

I was trying to build `noise-c` project using description below.
https://rweather.github.io/noise-c/index.html

And I got the error with a message like below:

```
gcc: error: proto3-lexer.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
```

I installed `bison` & `flex` using the commands below:

```
$ sudo apt install bison    
$ sudo apt install flex
```

Would you please give me idea what I'm missing or I didn't do correct way?

Comment: Perhaps you could give a hint about what you did (exactly, blow by blow) which triggered that error message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm solve this problem for me:
after installation `bison` & `flex` I'm reconfigure project

```
autoreconf -i
./configure
make
```